# How to hide specific columns in Excel up to specific cell position?

Tags: microsoft-excel

Every time I hide a column, the whole column is hidden. The problem is the down the bottom of the file in the same column there is data I still need to access after hiding the column. Is there a way I can hide a column from cell position to another in the same column?

Comment: I don't think it is possible but what i can image you can make those cells locked and mask them using `VBA` so that one cannot see what is there.

Comment: Seems like the simpliest thing would be to just move the hiden content to a visible cell. What's the reason this can't be done?